# Retrieve Apple in-app purchase transaction tax amount

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I am implementing the API backend for Apple in-app purchases receipt validation. I wish to record the transaction including tax in a `transactions` table in my database for record keeping. How can I be able to retrieve the transaction details; amount paid and tax amount. Can my iOS developer pass me the tax amount in their REST call to my API for receipt validation. Or perhaps, with the transaction reference (`unique_identifier` or `transaction_id`) I'm able to make a REST call to apple after the fact. My Apple/iOS knowledge itself is very limited. Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe that you should rely on IAP purchase events to determine tax liability; you should use the formal information provided by Apple at the end of each period.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not. I just want to be able to record what apple had charged my user (base price plus tax). If possible, of course. Thanks (Wondering if I can get it on the spot rather than end of period; I have a "Transaction History" view in my app where I'd like to display this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @twgerard no, I haven't, sorry.